# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result when I have 2 parameters

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, authentication

So I have this error :

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1
>   to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\wamp\www\Foredeck\login.php on
>   line 101 .

I did some research on internet but still don't understand where is the error. I think I have two parameters here. So what's wrong?

I'm new on PHP by the way.

```php
<?php
include("bdconnect_Foredeck.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $login, $pass, $dbname);
$msg  = '';

if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

  $Identifiant = $_POST["username"];
  $MotPasse    = $_POST["password"];
  $query       = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM   admin 
    WHERE  identifiant = '$Identifiant' 
           AND mdp_admin = '$MotPasse'";
  $result      = mysqli_query($link, $query);
  $row         = mysqli_fetch_array($query); //Line 101//

  if ($row) {
    $_SESSION['valid']   = true;
    $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
    $msg                 = 'Connexion Réussite';

    if ($_POST['username'] == 'Isabelle' && $_POST['password'] == 'Isabelle1') {

      $_SESSION['username'] = $_row['Identifiant'];
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Connexion Réussite');
window.location='foredeck_superadmin.php'; </script>";
      header("refresh:3 location: foredeck_superadmin.php");

    } else {

      $_SESSION['username'] = 'foredeckadmin';
      echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Connexion Réussite');
window.location='foredeck.php'; </script>";
      header("refresh:3 location: foredeck.php");

    }

  }

} else {
  $msg = 'Identifiant ou Mot de Passe incorrecte';
  $msg = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg')</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Should be `mysqli_fetch_array($result);`. `$query` hold the query string not the result resource

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array($result);`  not `$query`

Comment: still get the same error @Anant

Comment: @A.V  try to use code of this link:- https://eval.in/736497   (Don't see the output, just copy-paste code and check and tell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);` in place of   `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);`

As mysqli_fetch_array() function fetches a result row as an associative array and you were passing **$query** which is of type **string**. So, its throwing error.

Comment: You should explain why.

Comment: still get the same error even if i did like you said @Naincy

Comment: share the print_r of $result;

Comment: your query doesn't return anything. Please check your sql.

Comment: I did try this query on Navicat and it return values . @Naincy

Comment: Please do echo $query and run in SQL. once again.

Comment: Ok i did try it with numbers and it work but not working with letters @Naincy

Comment: Share DB fields datatypes or query that you echoed what is working and what's not.

Comment: It's ok  i did truncate table and add some new admin account  and now it's working . @Naincy

Answer (score 1):

Well `mysqli_fetch_array()` function accepts 2 parameters. the first is the result of your query then the second parameter accept which result type you want to get. choices are `MYSQLI_NUM`<- this is when you want to fetch the data by its position
 and `MYSQLI_ASSOC` <- reference the fetch data by its row name. the third choice is `MYSQLI_BOTH` if you want both make a reference as `MYSQLI_NUM` and `MYSQLI_ASSOC`

Answer (score 1):

Try below syntax for fetch record

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   // Print Record
}
```